# AngularJS - Display ng-repeat multi arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have the following list with multiple array:
http://hpics.li/8fcfac4

I would like the display the name with AngularJS.
So I am doing:

```
<li data-ng-repeat="deals in filteredDestinations | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize">{{deals.name}}</li>
```

It like an array of an array?!

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very hard to understand but I may have a solution for you. Since you have an array called images you will need to loop through that once more.

```
<li data-ng-repeat="deals in filteredDestinations | startFrom:(currentPage - 1)*pageSize |    limitTopageSize">
    <span ng-repeat="image in deals.images">
       {{image.name}}
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
<span ng-repeat="singleParent in parentArray">
    <span ng-repeat="childItem in singleParent.childArray">
        {{childItem.name}}
    </span>
</span>
```